# Delete an element from a hash based on a condition

Tags: ruby, hash

I have these parameters:

```
Parameters: {transactions"=>{
  "2"=>{"amount"=>"10", "finance_id"=>"4", "payee_id"=>"5", "category_id"=>"14", "payee_type"=>"Student", "transaction_date"=>"2015-08-10", "title"=>"Receipt No.. (Multiple Fees) F4", "finance_type"=>"FinanceFee", "payment_mode"=>"Cash", "payment_note"=>""},
  "1"=>{"amount"=>"10", "finance_id"=>"4", "payee_id"=>"2", "category_id"=>"14", "payee_type"=>"Student", "transaction_date"=>"2015-08-10", "title"=>"Receipt No.. (Multiple Fees) F4", "finance_type"=>"FinanceFee", "payment_mode"=>"Cash", "payment_note"=>""}
}}
```

I need to set a condition to delete the transaction with `amount = 0`.I tried this:

```
params[:transactions].each do |trans|
  trans.delete_if {|amount, value| value == 0 || value.nil? || value.empty?} 
end
```

but this doesn't delet the transaction with `amount` `0`.

Comment: or `value.to_i == 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this

```
transactions = {
    "transactions" =>
        {
            "2" => {
                "amount" => "10",
                "finance_id" => "4",
                "payee_id" => "5",


    "category_id" => "14",
            "payee_type" => "Student",
            "transaction_date" => "2015-08-10",
            "title" => "Receipt No.. (Multiple Fees) F4",
            "finance_type" => "FinanceFee",
            "payment_mode" => "Cash",
            "payment_note" => ""
        },
        "1" => {
            "amount" => "10",
            "finance_id" => "4",
            "payee_id" => "2",
            "category_id" => "14",
            "payee_type" => "Student",
            "transaction_date" => "2015-08-10",
            "title" => "Receipt No.. (Multiple Fees) F4",
            "finance_type" => "FinanceFee",
            "payment_mode" => "Cash",
            "payment_note" => ""
        },
        "3" => {
            "amount" => "0",
            "finance_id" => "4",
            "payee_id" => "2",
            "category_id" => "14",
            "payee_type" => "Student",
            "transaction_date" => "2015-08-10",
            "title" => "Receipt No.. (Multiple Fees) F4",
            "finance_type" => "FinanceFee",
            "payment_mode" => "Cash",
            "payment_note" => ""
        },
        "4" => {
            "amount" => nil,
            "finance_id" => "4",
            "payee_id" => "2",
            "category_id" => "14",
            "payee_type" => "Student",
            "transaction_date" => "2015-08-10",
            "title" => "Receipt No.. (Multiple Fees) F4",
            "finance_type" => "FinanceFee",
            "payment_mode" => "Cash",
            "payment_note" => ""
        },
        "4" => {
            "amount" => "",
            "finance_id" => "4",
            "payee_id" => "2",
            "category_id" => "14",
            "payee_type" => "Student",
            "transaction_date" => "2015-08-10",
            "title" => "Receipt No.. (Multiple Fees) F4",
            "finance_type" => "FinanceFee",
            "payment_mode" => "Cash",
            "payment_note" => ""
            }
        }
}

transactions["transactions"].delete_if{|_, v| v["amount"].to_s.strip.to_i == 0}
```

Comment: Thank you soooooooooo much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your value is an string convert this to integer

```
value.to_i == 0
```

or

```
value == 0.to_s
```

or

```
value.to_i.zero?
```